modify tikz arrow tips for a chain of arrows
I want to draw a directed graphs and put a big arrow tip at the end of each edge.  For large arrow tip I follow the suggestion in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30822634/how-to-change-arrow-tip-in-tikz
But when I implement in this in my tex code it only put the arrow tip in the first edge of a chain:
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz,mathdots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (-0.5,1) -- (0,1.5) -- (0.5,1) -- (0,0.5) -- (-0.5,1);
  \draw [-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (0,1.5) -- (0,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Is there a better way to do this other than manually drawing each edge separately?
THANKS!

See this answer which uses a decoration

Put them on a chain, make them an actual graph, use a tree, use a loop (maybe) .... But if it is a single path, it can only have arrow specifications at the two ends. A decoration is possible, but seems semantically out of place here?

Arrow tips only appear at the last segment of a path, each only once. That's just how arrow tips work with PGF.
I would recommend you use proper nodes/coordinates and separate edges if this is actually a graph. I'll show a few solutions in the code below, using

manual placement of nodes and a few edges,
placement by the chains library which also includes all but one of the edges and
the graphs library and its short syntax.

Nonetheless, the first TikZ picture uses the arrow pic which places arrow tips according to the “timer“ (the pos value) along a path operation (here -- = line to): The every to style is setup so that you don't have to add this pic every time.
You should at least give the coordinates a name so you can refer to them later again without having to input the coordinate specification again.
Code
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}

\tikzset{Big Stealth/.tip= {Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}}
\tikzset{
  pics/arrow/.style={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down, code=%
    \pgfarrowdraw{#1}}, pics/arrow/.default=>}
\begin{document}
\tikz[> = Big Stealth]
  \draw[every to/.append style={at end, edge node=pic{arrow}}]
   (-0.5,1) to (0,1.5) coordinate (2) to (0.5,1)
            to (0,0.5) coordinate (4) to cycle
   (2) to (4);

\tikz[> = Big Stealth, coordinate]
  \node foreach \i in {1, ..., 4}
    (\i) at (270-\i*90:.5) {\i}
    [->]
    (1) edge (2) (2) edge (3) edge (4)
    (3) edge (4) (4) edge (1);

\tikz[
  > = Big Stealth, coordinate,
  start chain=placed {at = (270-\tikzchaincount*90:.5)},
  every on chain/.append style=join,
  every edge/.append style=->
] \node foreach \i in {1, ..., 4}
   [on chain] {\i}
   (chain-end) edge (chain-begin)
   (chain-2) edge (chain-4);
 
\tikz[> = Big Stealth]
  \graph[radius=.5cm, phase=180, clockwise, nodes=coordinate]{
    subgraph I_n[n=4, ->, cycle];
    2 -> 4
  };
\end{document}

Output

